# Can not read my TIFF with lapply function

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, error

I want to read my TIFF files in the same folder at the same time (about 4.4MB), so I use the `lapply` function to read this.

(If you want to see which raster they are, download them in https://www.worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html

[image])

```
setwd("z:\\NTU\\master research\\GIS data\\WorldClim\\wc2.1_30s_tavg") # the folder that TIFFs store in
filelist <- list.files("z:\\NTU\\master research\\GIS data\\WorldClim\\wc2.1_30s_tavg", pattern = "")
tavg.list <- lapply(filelist, FUN = function(x) raster(x))
```

However I get this error:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.
```

It is weird that I can read this one by one. No error occurs.

```
tavg1 <- raster(filelist[[1]])
```

Can someone tell me about this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: You might want to try using `list.files(..., pattern = "*.tif")`. See if that works

Comment: Try instead `FUN = function(x) {message("loading ",x);raster(x)}` to see where its failing. If that's a TIF, then maybe its broken. If its not a TIF then you need to change your `filelist` to remove it.

Comment: You are leaving the pattern blank which is probably picking up another file in the directory. Using "*.tif" as the wildcard does not work for regex, the correct syntax is "tif$"

Answer (score 2):

Did you inspect `filelist`? It probably includes `.zip` or other files. To only select files that end on `.tif` do

```
 filelist <- list.files(pattern = "\\.tif$")
```

`$` means "the filename must end on these preceding characters", and `\\.` means "there really must be a point". If you did `.tif$` the point symbol would be interpreted as a wild-card for *any*  character.

This simpler version should also work:

```
 filelist <- list.files(pattern = "tif$")
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem as OP.... I've tried all the different patterns and it still doesn't work... Any other suggestions?

Comment: There is no way to respond to "it does not work". It is best to ask a new question is your situation is different.